# How do I change the transition level in SVG?

Tags: css, html, svg, css-transitions

**I need help with**

I am trying to make and HTML5 logo using SVG. The HTML5 logo is half dark orange and half orange. I want to use the linearGradient tag to do this but the gradient has a smooth transition and I need an instant transition for the logo.

**Code**

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
              <title>HTML SVG</title>
        </head>
    <body>

    <svg viewbox="0 0 150 150">

        <defs>

            <linearGradient id="gradient">

                <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
                <stop class="stop2" offset="50%"/>

            </linearGradient>

        </defs>

        <polygon id="polygon" fill="#E34C26" stroke="#E34C26" stroke-width="5" points="10 10, 90 10, 85 95, 50 105, 15 95"/>

    </svg>

</body>
```

*CSS*

```
<style>

    #polygon { fill:url(#gradient) }
    .stop1 { stop-color:#E34C26 }
    .stop2 { stop-color:#F06529 }

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add another stop at 50% equal to the starting colour. This will stop the first colour and start the second at exactly the same point, essentially removing the transition between the two.

```css
#polygon {
  fill: url(#gradient)
}

.stop1,
.stop2 {
  stop-color: #E34C26
}

.stop3 {
  stop-color: #F06529
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 150 150">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient">
            <stop class="stop1" offset="0%"/>
            <stop class="stop2" offset="50%"/>
            <stop class="stop3" offset="50%"/>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <polygon id="polygon" fill="#E34C26" stroke="#E34C26" stroke-width="5" points="10 10, 90 10, 85 95, 50 105, 15 95"/>
</svg>
```